# Jquery css animation

Tags: jquery

как вызывать функцию по завершении анимации

```
$s.css({"opacity": 0}, 500).removeClass("active");
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/  
Надо задать функцию complete

Comment: transitionEnd — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794148/css3-transition-events

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вот так будет более правильно.

$('#selector').animate({opacity:0},500,function(){
    alert('Анимация завершилась');
});

Более развернутый пример тут - http://jsfiddle.net/Rigiytip/R2hF4/